# ошибка missing return statement

Tags: java

Метод должен возвращать true если строка(str) начинается с "hi", иначе возвращает false

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
  String w = str.substring(0,2); // w = первые 2 символа str
  if ( str.length() > 2 ) {
    if(str.equals("hi")) {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

но выдает следующую ошибку

> missing return statement line:10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Причина проблемы:**

В случае входа в `if ( str.length() > 2 )`), но не попадания во вложенный `if(str.equals("hi"))`, окажется, что отсутствует конструкция `return`, которую следует исполнить потоку.

**Как исправить:**

Существует множество способов, к примеру, извлечь конструкцию `return false`; из блока `else`:

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {      
  if (str.length() >= 2) {
    String w = str.substring(0, 2); // w = первые 2 символа str
    if (w.equals("hi")) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Но логичнее сразу написать следующее:

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
  return str.substring(0, 2).equals("hi");
}
```

А еще логичнее воспользоваться методом `startsWith`:

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
  return str.startsWith("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам переменная w, если она не используется?  Этот метод будет возвращать true, если вся строка равна "hi".